# How to display in Big Query ONLY duplicated records?

Tags: google-bigquery

To view records without duplicated ones, I use this SQL

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number)
FROM (SELECT*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderid) row_number
FROM `TABLE`)
WHERE row_number = 1
```

What is the best practice to display only duplicated records from a single table?

Comment: Have you considered using HAVING ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just change the `row_number` ? You have partitionned by `order id`, creating partitions of duplicates, ranked the records and take only the first element to remove the duplicates. But if you take only the `row_number = 2`, you'll have only elements from partitions with at least 2 elements, i.e only duplicates.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number)
FROM (SELECT*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderid) row_number
FROM `TABLE`)
WHERE row_number = 2
```

**Note** :Use `row_number = 2` will give you only 1 element of duplicates. If you go with `row_number > 1`, the result may contain duplicates again (for example if you had 3 identical elements in the first table).

Answer (score 8):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Me personally, I prefer not to rely on ROW_NUMBER() whenever it is possible because with big volume of data it tends to lead to Resource Exceeded error

So, from my experience I would recommend below options:

To view records for those orderid with only one entry:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t) 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY orderid
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

to view records for those orderid with more than one entry:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag) FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY orderid) > 1 flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
) 
WHERE flag
```

*note: behind the hood - COUNT(1) OVER() can be calculated using as many workers as available while ROW_NUMBER() OVER() requires all respective data to be moved to one worker (thus Resource related issue)*

OR

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE orderid IN (
  SELECT orderid FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY orderid HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for this input, your answer just helped me with one of my queries

Answer (score 3):

You can display the duplicated row by showing only raw with `row_number` greater than 1.

```sql
select
  * except(row_number)
from (
  select
    *, row_number() over (partition by ) as row_number
  from `TABLE`)
where row_number > 1
```

Answer (score -2):

If your table has not primary key column, you are obliged to define it. Asuming my table contains 12 columns in BigQuery, I do not find shorter than:

```sql
SELECT *, sum(1) as rowcount
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
HAVING rowcount>1;
```